# MemoryMappedFile without a real file

Tags: java, file, memory

I can define and use a RandomAccessFile/MemoryMappedFile, which I am using for inter-JVM communication. It's basically a memory-only scratchpad that never needs to actually be written to disk.

But starting it up, especially a large one, takes time, because the file system needs to be involved to allocate a real file on disk.

Is there a way to use a MemoryMappedFile *without* involving the real file system?